Why does the variable j in the following code takes the input value at 15th iteration?
I was impressed with the class 3 on arrays from cs50 and I have written the following code in which I've written two initializations, two conditions and one increment operator on j. It is a buggy logic which should run infinitely. But at 15th iteration the variable j is taking the value that was entered and terminating unconditionally. Any help would be appreciated.
The expected output is it should take 3x3 matrix and output 3x3 matrix. Even though the 15th element is out of the scope, I am interested to know the reason behind the input value  being taken to variable j.
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>

int main(void){
    int matrix[3][3];
    for(int i=0,j=0;i<3,j<3;j++){
        matrix[i][j] = get_int("Please enter %i th and %i th element of matrix \n",i,j);
        if( j==2) { i++;j=-1; }
    }
    for(int i=0,j=0;i<3,j<4;j++){
        printf("%i \t",matrix[i][j]);
        if( j==2) { i++;j=0;printf("\n"); }
    }
}


Note that the comma operator makes the expression i<3,j<3 equal to j<3. The check for i<3 is lost. You need i < 3 && j < 3.

But why is it that the variable j taking the input value at 15th iteration, instead of running infinitely

As a beginner you should neither be writing nor studying messy code like this. CS50 has a nasty reputation, consider getting a good C book instead.

@Someprogrammerdude: element matrix[i][-1] is not accessed because j is incremented in the last clause of the for statement. Yet matrix[4][0] is modified causing undefined behavior.  Such clever coding must banned. I hope they do not teach this at Harvard's CS50 course...

The code has undefined behaviour, therefore questions of the kind "why does it do this and not that" are meaningless.

@shiva: you can accept an answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.


But at 15th iteration the variable j is taking the value that was entered and terminating unconditionally.

When i goes out of bounds and matrix[i][j] = … attempts to write a value, it may write a value in memory outside of matrix. Likely, at the time where you see this behavior, the memory nominally corresponding to matrix[i][j] is the memory used for j, so the assignment changes the value of j.

There are multiple problems:

the condition i<3,j<3 evaluates as j < 3 and thus the loop runs for ever because you reset j to -1 whenever it reaches 2.
this causes the program to initialize the element at matrix[4][0], which is beyond the end of the 2D array, causing undefined behavior.
it is futile trying to make sense of further observations in the debugger once you invoke undefined behavior: anything can happen. including j getting modified or something more obscure causing the value shown to be meaningless.
the condition i<3,j<4 in the second loop is just as useless as the one in the first loop since j never passes 2.
you should refrain from cramming multiple statements on a single line and using clever ways to pack loops.  Write the code as clearly and simply as possible, using consistent spacing and indentation, and let the compiler optimize the generated code, they are much more efficient at that than most programmers out there.

Here is a modified version:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

enum { ROWS = 3, COLS = 3 };

int main(void) {
    int matrix[ROWS][COLS];

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = get_int("Please enter the value of matrix[%d][%d]\n", i, j);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

